# How to loop through a JSON array of objects in bash which includes space characters

Tags: json, bash, jq

I'm calling an API which returns a JSON response that includes an array of objects. I would like to store the objects in an array in bash which I want to loop through.

It has worked for me to use `jq -c` to make use of the compact output:

```
json_response='{"value":[{"displayName":"1"},{"displayName":"2"},{"displayName":"3"}]}'

workspaces=$(echo $json_response | jq -c '.value.[]')

for workspace in ${workspaces[@]}; do
    echo $workspace
done
```

This is the output:

```
{"displayName":"1"}
{"displayName":"2"}
{"displayName":"3"}
```

However, this doesn't work if there is a space character in the `displayName`:

```
json_response='{"value":[{"displayName":"1"},{"displayName":"2"},{"displayName":"3"},{"displayName":"Has Space"}]}'
    
workspaces=$(echo $json_response | jq -c '.value.[]')
    
for workspace in ${workspaces[@]}; do
    echo $workspace
done
```

The output then contains a line break where the space character was:

```
{"displayName":"1"}
{"displayName":"2"}
{"displayName":"3"}
{"displayName":"Has
Space"}
```

How can I still loop through the objects even if there is a space character?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: You should consider doing to loop work in jq tho.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer? Where should I put the quotes, I tried putting them around $json_response but it didn't change the result. Also, what do you mean by looping in jq? I only found this anser, which is similar to what I'm doing now, except for being more compact.

Comment: Please show your desired output of the loop.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should quote (`""`) all bash variables that might contain a space

   - [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)
2. Prever `jq '.' <<< "$some_var"` over using `echo $some_var | jq`

   - [echo vs <<<, or Useless Use of echo in Bash Award?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59007/echo-vs-or-useless-use-of-echo-in-bash-award)
3. Use `readarray` to create a bash array of jq's output

---

```bash
#!/bin/bash

json_response='{"value":[{"displayName":"1"},{"displayName":"2"},{"displayName":"3"},{"displayName":"Has Space"}]}'

readarray -t workspaces < <(jq -c '.value[]' <<< "$json_response")

for workspace in "${workspaces[@]}"; do
    echo "--> $workspace <--"
done
```

Gives the following on bash 4.4.20

```
--> {"displayName":"1"} <--
--> {"displayName":"2"} <--
--> {"displayName":"3"} <--
--> {"displayName":"Has Space"} <--
```

---

Regarding my *You should consider doing to loop work in jq tho* comment;

- You're already looping over the array in JQ, so why not use that to create the desired output so you don't need to capture the output in a bash array an looping over that, instead, convert all your magic to jq if possible

Comment: Thank you, I missed putting the ${workspaces[@]} inside quotes as well. Also, thanks for the additional hints for improving my code with <<< and jq.